# How to convert os.File to *multipart.FileHeader in Go?

Tags: go

I'm writing test for a function like this.

```golang
type Form struct {
    Message     string
    Attachments []*multipart.FileHeader
}

func Submit(form *Form) {
    // submit the form
}
```

I want to create a `Form` instance with a slice of *multipart.FileHeader. I have some file that can be used for the test, and I can open them with `os.Open()`, which returns `*os.File`. I also tried to use `&multipart.FileHeader{Filename: "/path/to/file"}`, but that didn't work (cannot be opened). How can I convert `*os.File` to `*multipart.FileHeader` in Go? I do know I can do that with the `multipart.NewWriter()` method and mock an http request, but I want to know whether there's a simpler way.

Comment: You could use [`(*multipart.Reader) ReadForm`](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart@go1.17.5#Reader.ReadForm) and then extract the headers using the [`File`](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart@go1.17.5#Form.File) field. But the content of the `*os.File` or whatever `io.Reader` you decide to use, must contian a valid multipart form, otherwise the ReadForm will return an error.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/vTwzCR9Nktx

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced a similar case, and I ended up using this method. I think the code below is self-explanatory

```
func createMultipartFileHeader(filePath string) *multipart.FileHeader {
    // open the file
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // create a buffer to hold the file in memory
    var buff bytes.Buffer
    buffWriter := io.Writer(&buff)

    // create a new form and create a new file field
    formWriter := multipart.NewWriter(buffWriter)
    formPart, err := formWriter.CreateFormFile("file", filepath.Base(file.Name()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil
    }

    // copy the content of the file to the form's file field
    if _, err := io.Copy(formPart, file); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil
    }

    // close the form writer after the copying process is finished
    // I don't use defer in here to avoid unexpected EOF error
    formWriter.Close()

    // transform the bytes buffer into a form reader
    buffReader := bytes.NewReader(buff.Bytes())
    formReader := multipart.NewReader(buffReader, formWriter.Boundary())

    // read the form components with max stored memory of 1MB
    multipartForm, err := formReader.ReadForm(1 << 20)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil
    }

    // return the multipart file header
    files, exists := multipartForm.File["file"]
    if !exists || len(files) == 0 {
        log.Fatal("multipart file not exists")
        return nil
    }

    return files[0]
}
```